# Emberjs, Disable singleton for a specific view

Tags: ember.js

When I add multiple instance of the same type of views in an containerView there are in fact the same instance. How I can make them distinct instances ?

I've created a little jsbin to illustrate the situation. The title of the three 'windows' should be "First window", "Default title" and "Third window" but all have the "Third window" title.

I've tried to register my view with singleton option to false but without any success.

> App.register('view:window', App.Window, { singleton: false })

http://jsbin.com/oHEweXO/10/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `create` use `extend` in your subviews, so ember will instantiate new subviews each time that a new `App.Window` is created:

```
App.Window = Ember.ContainerView.extend
  classNames: ['window']
  childViews: ['headerView', 'bodyView', 'footerView']  
  title: 'Default title'
  headerView:
    Ember.View.extend   // <= extend instead of create         
      classNames: ['window-header']
      template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{ view.parentView.title }}')

  bodyView:
    Ember.View.extend  // <= extend instead of create         
      classNames: ['window-body']
      template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Body')

  footerView:
    Ember.View.extend  // <= extend instead of create         
      classNames: ['window-footer']
      template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Footer')
```

Using just `create` you will have a single instance of each shared subview shared by any created `App.Window`. Like this:

```
App.Window = Ember.Container.extend
  headerView:
    instance h1
  bodyView:
    instance b1
  ...

w1 = App.Window.create()
w1.get('childViews') // [instance h1, instance h2]

w2 = App.Window.create()
w2.get('childViews') // [instance h1, instance h2]

etc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that clean answer. I think I better understand what's going on now.

Comment: You are welcome! I understand your mistake, in the guides http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html, all the time is used `create` in subviews, but all the time is created a new CollectionView instance. Maybe need to have some warning about the usage when extending ...